# Any examples of using multilogicadapter in chatterbot?

Tags: python-3.x, chatterbot

I am trying to combine multiple logic adapters in Python chatterbot.  I cannot seem to get it right.  I tried this:

```
english_bot = ChatBot("English Bot", 
storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
multi_logic_adapter = [
    "chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
    "chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter",
    "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"]
)
```

Only BestMatch seems to be active
And I tried this:

```
english_bot = ChatBot("English Bot", 
storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
logic_adapter = [
    "chatterbot.logic.multi_adapter.MultiLogicAdapter", 
    "chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
    "chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter",
    "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"]
)
```

But I get this error:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'confidence' and none of the logic_adapters seems to be active.

Thanks,
Herb

Answer (score 0):

> BestMatch

Adapter is the default adapter for chatterbot, You don't need explicitly specify that. More information http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/index.html#best-match-adapter

And you code should like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = ChatBot(
    "English Bot",
    logic_adapters=[
        "chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
        "chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter"
    ]
)

# Print an example of getting one math based response
response = bot.get_response("What is 4 + 9?")
print(response)

# Print an example of getting one time based response
response = bot.get_response("What time is it?")
print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not address the problem.  If I do what you suggest, I can get math answers and time answers, but no text answers.  For example: **Who is the author of Frankenstein?**  The current time is 08:52 AM  **what is 4 + 7?**  ( 4 + 7 ) = 11.  I want to be able to answer all three kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Every logic adapter in `logic_adapters=[]` is **automatically** processed by MultiLogicAdapter. You might need to tweak the confidence levels though.

More info about the MultiLogicAdapter here:
http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/multi-logic-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Multi Logic adapter is an inbuilt class and is not explicitly defined in the code.You can see this statement in the introduction part:"ChatterBot **internally** uses a special logic adapter that allows it to choose the best response generated by any number of other logic adapters" This is the link - http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/multi-logic-adapter.html

Also, similar query is already available on stackover flow. Refer this as well.
[Error while using chatterbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332932/error-while-using-chatterbot)

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiLogicAdapter` typically doesn't get used directly in this way.

Each logic adapter that you add to the `logic_adapters=[]` will get processed by the `MultiLogicAdapter` internally by ChatterBot, no need to explicitly specify it.