# Error while using chatterbot

Tags: python-3.x, chatterbot

I'm trying to make a simple QnA program using Python chatterbot.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = ChatBot(
    "SQLMemoryTerminal",
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    logic_adapters=[
        {
            "import_path": "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch",
            "statement_comparison_function": 
"chatterbot.comparisons.levenshtein_distance"
        },
        {
            'import_path' : 'chatterbot.logic.LowConfidenceAdapter',
            'threshold' : 0.3,
            'default_response' : "Sorry. I can not find the exact answer."
        },
        'chatterbot.logic.multi_adapter.MultiLogicAdapter',
    ],
    input_adapter="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",
    output_adapter="chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter",
    read_only= True
)

print("input question")

while True:
    try:
        print("Q : ",end="")
        bot_input = bot.get_response(None)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

However, when I try to use the multiadapter function built in chatterbot, I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KPvoice/PycharmProjects/Contact/ChatterbotTest.py", line 
30, in <module>
    bot_input = bot.get_response(None)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 113, 
in get_response
    statement, response = self.generate_response(input_statement, 
conversation_id)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 132, 
in generate_response
    response = self.logic.process(input_statement)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\logic\multi_adapter.py", 
line 52, in process
    output = adapter.process(statement)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\logic\multi_adapter.py", 
line  89, in process
    result.confidence = max_confidence
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'confidence'
```

I do not know how to solve it.

The working environment is Windows 10, Python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MultiLogicAdapter` typically doesn't get used directly in this way.

Each logic adapter that you add to the `logic_adapters=[]` will get processed by the `MultiLogicAdapter` internally by ChatterBot, no need to explicitly specify it.